# CKEditor Rails blank page after youtube-video added on update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, ckeditor

I use ckeditor gem https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/
I add video from youtube on edit page and click Save -> blank page, and in URL-adress there is "data:," (every time same).
Content of editor saved, but every time user needs to click "back" button.

I use google and found just this: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL

P.S.: in Firefox there isn't this bug, only in Chromium/Chrome

Rails 4, in dev/prod both

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, I suspect most users will too.

If I get time today I plan on investigating this further but for now I will raise an issue in the Github Repo.

Answer (score -1):

I had a blank page issue after upgrading to the newest ckeditor 4.5. All I did to correct it is to go the top of the browser of the editing page and refresh. Then everything started populating correctly. I hope this works for you as well. Give a feedback if it works. Thanks.